# Using Nashorn with other Web Application Framework

Tags: java, jsf, wicket, oracle-adf, nashorn

In JavaOne 2013 I attended a seminar on Project Nashorn. I was astonished after knowing about it. Calling Java From JavaScript and vice versa.

But one question is still unclear to me, that how can we use Nashorn in favor of Web Application Framework like JSF, ADF Faces or Wicket etc. If someone give any pointer, it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: J1 2013 hasn't happened just yet.. Must be 2012, I believe.

Comment: @AntonArhipov J1 2013 already happened on April, in India. http://www.oracle.com/javaone/in-en/index.html. Next will be in San Francisco, 22 to 26 September.

Comment: As node.jar is not available yet, we can only improvise, e.g.: http://marcelorjava.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/code-walkthrough-online-kanban-board-with-nashorn/

Comment: @theMarceloR avatarjs is a new name of node.jar https://avatar-js.java.net/

Comment: Hi @Vik_Gamov, yeah, Marcus told me about it on Twitter a while ago, unfortunately, I didn't have a chance to play with it yet :(

Answer (score 3):

Scripting API for Java Platform, in general, and Nashorn, in particular, open wide range of opportunities for web app development on JVM. Frameworks like node.js and vert.x solvency of JavaScript as server-side framework. Yes, we still waiting news about node.jar - mystery Oracle's project of implementing node.js API on Java platform.

In todays modern web applications we should think about server-side more as service provider (RESTful services) rather than presentation framework that generates html on the server. But even for server-generated pages you not necessarily need stick to frameworks like JSF, Wicket, ADF. With Nashorn/Rhino you can use JavaScript templates to generate html markup on the backend. LinkedIn, for instance, [already described](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) benefits of having templates written in JavaScript in both browser and on the server. In case when your browser unable to precess client-side templates you can graceful degrade and switch to server-side rendering.

If you're looking to example for to leverage JavaScript in server-side web framework you can start with [Dust4j](https://github.com/noroutine/dust4j/tree/master/src/main/java/me/noroutine/dust4j). Do not be confused by words Rhino in description. Dust4j doesn't use internal Rhino's APIs. It uses jsr223 APIs so if you run it on JDK8 or [JDK7 with Nashorn backport](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/03/how-to-make-use-of-nashorn-on-java-7/) it should work. Dust4j project shows how you can integrate scripting into you JSP/Servlet/Filter-based application.

Answer (score 2):

Nashorn is a JavaScript compiler and runtime for the Java Virtual Machine.   It is not a Web Application Framework in itself, but might enable one to be built on top of it.

Therefore, it isn't a replacement for JSF or ADF.

Comment: heh, a search for '"web application framework" nashorn' returns this as the first result.  Guess that's just a hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Wicket provides a functionality to post javascript code against the server, now and also allow to access session / request scoped objects. It does not replace the Web Framework itself, but allows you to create a programming interface to run code on the server and modify java objects, calculate values and return the calculcation.

The documentation of Wicket's Nashorn Integration can be found here: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/NashornIntegration

And if you fork the git repository you can run the nashorn integration examples:
https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/nashorn-parent/nashorn-examples

One thing left to be mentioned: Because it is an arbitrary code execution this might lead to security issues, so ensure that only logged in users can access this interface.